# How to download file from a "Download" folder using postman or API

Tags: java, excel, api, download, postman

In my application, after clicking export icon, the report excel has been downloaded/generated in our local download folder in the system. I have tried to  validate this action using service side (API)-postman. When I hit the export api (Application specific) , the response has not contain any path/file name that downloaded in the downloads folder. Is there any way that we can hit the downloads folder  using api or any java programming way to get the downloaded excel.

I just want to read the excel data and compare with my input data using postman. First priority that I need to do it using api.

Answer (score 2):

Select "Send and download" action in Postman. According to manual [here](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/responses/):

> If your API endpoint returns an image, Postman will detect and render
>   it automatically. For binary response types, you should select “Send
>   and download” which will let you save the response to your hard disk.
>   You can then view it using the appropriate viewer. This gives you the
>   flexibility to test audio files, PDFs, zip files, or anything that the
>   API throws at you.

Comment: Hi wolfetto, Actually while i hit export api, I am getting response as "success: true" and the excel has been downloaded in the download. Also, there is no reference to this download path or download file name/content in the api response.  So I think we can't use "Send and Download" action.

Comment: no we are not returning the path in the response wolfetto. But we know that it will be generated inthe download folder. Anyway that postman has liberty to hit the downloads folder using api ??.

Comment: is downloads folder inside server?

Comment: my system local downloads folder. yes inside server.

Comment: Once you have created the file in downloads you can call another endpoint to point the downloaded file, extract the information you are looking for etc etc. Of course, you must track the information about the file to retrieve it